# jQuery ajax error returns empty string

Tags: google-chrome, jquery

I'm using the below function to send an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data_params,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            ResultActions(result);
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            ShowLoadingAnimation();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $("body").removeClass('loading');
            $('#myModal_loading').hide();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (jqXHR.status == 0) {
                alert('xhr: ' + jqXHR.responseText + '\n' + 'status: ' + textStatus + '\n' + "error: " + errorThrown);
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
                $('#myModal_offline').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true });
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is with the error callback. One of our clients is experiencing an issue when calling the above ajax function. The loading animation appears (see beforeSend() ) and then the javascript alert pops up (error callback): jqXHR.responseText is empty, status is "error", the errorThrown is also emtpy.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Advised the client to empty the entire browser cache, cookies, etc.
- Added Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header to the server's response header
- Added Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT to the server's response header

I'm using this function in the entire application and no one else has experienced this issue. He's using the latest version of Chrome and has tried IE and different computers too, same story. One common part is that both computers are in the same network (office).

Please advise how to continue the investigation.

Comment: Are you saying this works fine for some people but not for others?

Comment: For what it's worth, I experienced the same problem when trying to access web services through a flaky wireless connexion. Most of the packets were dropped on the floor, and the access point died a few days later.

Comment: @Nunners I'm saying this works fine for everyone except one user.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi That's interesting, but I assume if that's the problem he'd experience issues with other sites, too.

Comment: I agree with frederic-hamidi but there are other possibilities as well. If the problem is not the specific network connection it could be the browser. Here are more questions to answer: Does he have security settings higher than others? Is he using a proxy? Does he have a VPN installed? Is he behind any kind of non-consumer grade firewall? Is he on an atypical OS platform (such as a mobile, linux or a gaming console)? Does his browser have plugins installed? Does he have anti-phishing software enabled on his computer? And I'm sure others can come up with more questions as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Luke, I have sent the questions to the client, I'll get back to you as soon as he replied.